# Escaping brackets in Clojure

Tags: regex, string, clojure

If I try this

```
(import java.util.regex.Pattern)
(Pattern/compile ")!@#$%^&*()")
```

or this

```
(def p #")!@#$%^&*()")
```

I have Clojure complaining that there is an unmatched / unclosed `)`. Why are brackets evaluated within this simple string? How to escape them? Thanks

**EDIT**: While escaping works in the clojure-specific syntax (`#""`), it doesn't work with the `Pattern/compile` syntax that I do need because I have to compile the regex patter dynamically  from a string.

I've tried with `re-pattern`, but I can't escape properly for some reason:

```
(re-pattern "\)!@#$%^&*\(\)")
    java.lang.Exception: Unsupported escape character: \)
    java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: ! in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
    java.lang.Exception: No dispatch macro for: $
    java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: % in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Metadata can only be applied to IMetas
```

**EDIT 2** This little function may help:

```
(defn escape-all [x]
    (str "\\" (reduce #(str  %1 "\\" %2) x)))
```

Comment: As an aside, I don't think you need the import, you could just use Clojure's `re-pattern` function.

Comment: you're right. still, I can't get it to work. see my edit, please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got it working by double escaping everything. Oh the joys of double escaping.

```
=> (re-pattern "\\)\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)")
=> #"\)\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)"

=> (re-find (re-pattern "\\)\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)")
            ")!@#$%^&*()")
=> ")!@#$%^&*()"
```

I would recommend writing a helper function `str-to-pattern` (or whatever you want to call it), that takes a string, double escapes everything it needs to, and then calls `re-pattern` on it.

**Edit: making a string to pattern function**
There are plenty of ways to do this, below is just one example. I start by making an smap of regex escape chars to their string replacement. An "smap" isn't an actual type, but functionally it's a map we will use to swap "old values" with "new values", where "old values" are members of the keys of the smap, and "new values" are corresponding members of the vals of smap. In our case, this smap looks like `{\( "\\(", \) "\\)" ...}`.

```
(def regex-char-esc-smap
  (let [esc-chars "()*&^%$#!"]
    (zipmap esc-chars
            (map #(str "\\" %) esc-chars))))
```

Next is the actual function. I use the above smap to replace items in the string passed to it, then convert that back into a string and make a regex pattern out of it. I think the `->>` macro makes the code more readable, but that's just a personal preference.

```
(defn str-to-pattern
  [string]
  (->> string
       (replace regex-char-esc-smap)
       (reduce str)
       re-pattern))
```

Answer (score 3):

are you sure the error is from the reader (ie from clojure itself)?

regexps use parentheses, and they have to match there too.  i would guess the error is cominng from the code trying to compile the regexp.

if you want to escape a paren in a regexp, use a backquote: `(def p #"\)!@#$%^&*\(\)")`

[update] ah, sorry, you probably need double escapes as Omri days.

Comment: @pistacchio I think you will have to double escape. I might suggest writing a help function `str-to-pattern` (or some similar name) that takes a string, double escapes the things it needs to, and then calls `re-pattern` on it.

Comment: Oh, I was suggesting making it yourself, not saying that it already exists. By the way, I've changed this to be an answer for the sake of clarity, and I'll also update soon with how you might write your own `str-to-pattern` function.

Answer (score 3):

All of the versions of Java that Clojure supports recognize `\Q` to start a quoted region and `\E` to end the quoted region. This allows you to do something like this:

```
(re-find #"\Q)!@#$%^&*()\E" ")!@#$%^&*()")
```

If you're using `(re-pattern)` then this will work:

```
(re-find (re-pattern "\\Q)!@#$%^&*()\\E") ")!@#$%^&*()")
```

If you're assembling a regular expression from a string whose content you don't know then you can use the `quote` method in `java.util.regex.Pattern`:

```
(re-find (re-pattern (java.util.regex.Pattern/quote some-str)) some-other-str)
```

Here's an example of this from my REPL:

```
user> (def the-string ")!@#$%^&*()")
#'user/the-string
user> (re-find (re-pattern (java.util.regex.Pattern/quote the-string)) the-string)
")!@#$%^&*()"
```